# Connect to node.socket file

Tags: cardano-node

I built a cardano node using docker and I created a volume in my root directory `./cardano-node-ipc:/ipc`. However I can't seem to find any information on how to interact with the `node.socket` file inside cardano-node-ipc. I am a Javascript developer and for learning purposes I'd just like to be able to build a basic app similar to https://explorer.cardano.org where I show transactions as they happen. Could someone give me tips on how to connect to the cardano network a see transactions? To be honest I'm not even sure if I am headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sam gives one possible path forward above.

However, since you mention https://explorer.cardano.org I should point out the official explorer (which is written in JS) uses the https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/ project to follow the chain and populate a Postgresql database. The explorer you are writing could then connect to the database.

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with it using the node to node protocol. This is the protocol that cardano-cli utilizes, as well as a 3rd party tool called cncli. cncli is a rust application that understands the chain sync protocol and can be found here: https://github.com/AndrewWestberg/cncli